# Extracting data from a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have created a custom listview with two TextViews with ID text1 and text2. text1 shows a place and text2 shows a description. At first when I implemented the onListItemClicked method and fed the data into a toast it showed the data in the first textview which is the place in text1. Now wanted to extract from text 2 so found an answered suggested by someone here on S/O but it now only extracts data from the text2 of the first list item and not where I have clicked. Any idea how to get data dynamically? Not familiar with data sources so all data is in 2arrays,or is there no way and I have to get data at that position from the second array that holds descriptions? 
Some code from the custom list class:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    View parentView =(View)v.getParent();
    String text;
    text=((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, text+" !here(description)",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: can you share your custom list class

Comment: the getView was just inflating the list by getting data from each array at the respective indices and feeding it into each textview,still need the code?

Comment: if your problem is solved no need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **View v** in **onListItemClick** represents the ViewGroup for the row you've clicked. Therefore, you don't need the **getParent** method. Change your code as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    String text;
    text=((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, text+" !here(description)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The parentView, as you have it, would refer to the entire ListView's view hierarchy. Within that, there would be multiple Views that each contain a TextView with id == R.id.text2. I would guess that findViewById would just grab the first one it finds in that hierarchy, which is why it's always returning the value from the first row.

Comment: @Raghunandan, As for the parentView, AFAIK, that would refer to the entire ListView's view hierarchy. Within that, there would be multiple Views that each contain a TextView with id == R.id.text2. I would guess that findViewById would just grab the first one it finds in that hierarchy, which is why it's always returning the value from the first row.

Comment: add this to your post this answers the actual question

Comment: Point taken, @Raghunandan. Though his question wasn't exactly "why", but "how".

Comment: adding a bit of explanation would make it clear well any case this should work

Comment: This actually totally worked,thanx alot. So when would u use the parentView?

Comment: I can't think of a reason to in this specific instance. As, in this case, parentView would refer to a ViewGroup containing a bunch of similar ViewGroups, it would get quite hairy. Normally you just need access to a specific row's ViewGroup, and the **View v** parameter provides you with that.